# How to Pass Variables to Javascript from C# using Invoke?

Tags: javascript, c#, parameter-passing, webbrowser-control

```
private void WebBrowser_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  wb.Navigate("C:/Users/intern3/source/repos/MarketingProject/Samples/WPF/RESTToolkitTestApp/index.htm");  
  wb.InvokeScript("SetCoords", new object[] { coord1, coord2 });
}
```

wb is a WebBrowser object

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=GetMap&key=AgCKDO35_SFD68BDTuy_QuFz48T2P3FmYQKttx8y2DXQNR-ufCeae5riWUYmPCmk' async defer></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        var map;
        var lattitude = 34.2;
        var longitude = -117.8;
        function SetCoords(lat, long) {
            lattitude = lat;
            longitude = long;
        }
...
```

I've tried adding the coordinates to the end of the url as a querystring but since it's a local file I don't think it's possible. If it is please let me know because that would be an easy solution to this too. But otherwise, this is giving me this error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Unknown name. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020006 (DISP_E_UNKNOWNNAME))'

Comment: Better use [WebView2](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/) nowadays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It takes some time until the `WebBrowser` control has loaded the page so that it knows the Javascript function. Instead of calling the function directly after the load, use a handler for the `LoadCompleted` event to run the function, e.g.:

```
public MyForm() // This is the constructor of your form/page
{
  InitializeComponent();
  wb.LoadCompleted += WebBrowser_LoadCompleted;
}

private void WebBrowser_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
 wb.Navigate("C:/Users/intern3/source/repos/MarketingProject/Samples/WPF/RESTToolkitTestApp/index.htm");  

}

private void WebBrowser_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
  wb.InvokeScript("SetCoords", new object[] { coord1, coord2 });
}
```

Above code adds the handler for `LoadCompleted` manually, but you can also add it in the designer.

Comment: Is there a way to do something like that(load completed event handler) on the Javascript file? Right now I'm resorting to a Refresh button to update the coordinates that I'm sending.